# Hibernate not inserting column in onetomany relationship

Tags: hibernate, spring, spring-mvc, one-to-many

I have two tables Person

```
@Id
@Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
@GeneratedValue
 public Integer getId() {
  return id;
 }

@Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
public String getFirstName() {
 return firstName;
}

@Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
public String getLastName() {
 return lastName;
}

@Column(name = "MONEY")
public Double getMoney() {
 return money;
}

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="person")
@JoinColumn(name="person_id")
public List<Passport> getPassports(){
      return this.passports;
 }
```

One person can have many passports :)

Passport

```
@Id
@Column(name = "passport_id")
@GeneratedValue
public Integer getPassport_id() {
    return passport_id;
}

@Column(name = "country_issue")
public String getCountry_issue() {
    return country_issue;
}


@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="person_id")
public Person getPerson(){
    return person;

}
```

in passport table everything is inserted except person_id

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before saving Person:

```
for(Passport passport : person.getPassports())
{
    passport.setPerson(person);
}

repo.save(person);
```

Bi-direcitonal relationships in Hibernate has to be setup explicitly.

Comment: I tried that and got this error  " Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`springdb`.`passports`, CONSTRAINT `FKC84AF6A118514A4B` FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`person_id`))"

Comment: i deleted that constraint and it worked . thanks buddy. i was trying for 4 days and no one mentioned that point . thanks

Comment: You should keep that constraint and have cascade=CascadeType.ALL attribute to your OneToMany annotation in your Person class.